# How to read RFID tag value using Wiegand protocol?

Tags: pi-pico, rfid

I am trying to read RFID tag values using Paxton P75 reader. Here I have already connected reader with wiznet w5500 pico. and apply https://github.com/Rajan244/RFID/blob/main/wiegand.py to read the values.

receiving output as below for the same tag each time receiving diff values, the tag actual value is `29714856` :

```
##RFID tag value: F33C9E67
##RFID tag value: F33C8F63
##RFID tag value: FFFFFF7F
##RFID tag value: FFFFFF7F
##RFID tag value: FFFFFF7F
```

From research found,

- paxton have following sort of code conversion https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/natmchugh/e8f08350a606dc68bbffbc0f6c44017b/raw/paxton-covert.html
- more this https://gist.github.com/natmchugh/18e82761dbce52fa284c87c190dc926f document show the way value the stores in fob.

Now, can you please guide how can I received the correct Page 4-5 OR hex output ?